# Does my multi-tenancy approach contain any serious flaws?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization, multi-tenant

For a web application I try to implement a multi-tenancy approach with a separate database for each tenant. The secured data is accessed by a path like:

```
http://myurl.com:8080/myapp/tenantId/path/to/data
e.g. access the profile data of john which belongs to tenant 1:
http://myurl.com:8080/myapp/1/john
```

The implementation of the tenant-specific data accesses was quite straightforward (if requested I will add the respective code here). However, I am not sure whether I am securing the data the right way. Here is what I did for the authentication: I implemented a filter to enhance user names with tenant ids:

```java
public class TenantUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private static final String delimiter = ":";
    private static final String tenantParameterIdentifier = "tenant";

    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = super.obtainUsername(request);
        // The login data is equipped with a 'tenant' field in a user-defined login page
        String tenant = request.getParameter(tenantParameterIdentifier);
        return tenant + delimiter + username;
    }
}
```

A `UserDetailsWithTenantService` uses this modified name to load the details for a specific user:

```java
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String tenantAndUsername) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
   ...
   return new TenantUser(userName, account.getPassword(), tenantName, authorities);
   ...
}
```

The authorization is accomplished by another filter and at this point I am quite uncertain if I am doing everything right:

```java
public class TenantAuthorizationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static final String loginPath = "/j_spring_security_check";
    private final static int tenantIndex = 1;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        actualDoFilter(req, res, chain);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private void actualDoFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) return;

        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal.equals("anonymousUser")) return;

        TenantUser userDetails = (TenantUser) principal;
        String requestServletPath = request.getServletPath();
        if (requestServletPath.equals(loginPath)) return;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(\\w*).*");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(requestServletPath);
        m.find();
        String requestedTenantName = m.group(tenantIndex);

        if (requestedTenantName.isEmpty()) return;

        String authenticatedTenantName = userDetails.getTenant();
        if (!authenticatedTenantName.equals(requestedTenantName)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("");
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the filter checks whether the authenticated user tries to access data of a different tenant than he is authorized to. In this case an according exception is thrown.

The two filters are configured in my `root-context.xml`:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="tenantAuthenticationFilter" />
  <!-- not sure whether this position for an authorization filter is recommended -->
  <custom-filter after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="tenantAuthorizationFilter" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the approach is fine. However, how about me sending another tenant code to Gail access to their data.

Ideally, there should be kind of rest type security system with the authorization header or to have the tenant identified by the login and each request to validate the parameter against the logged in tenant context.

I think this will make it secure than the current one. Please share with us your understanding.